# Getting inner text for line break by class name

Tags: vba, line, break, innertext

See my screenshot:

[image]

In the pic, I am trying to retrieve the highlighted line but unable to do so.

Can someone help me with this and some vba code?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your code.

Comment: Set ky = Doc.getElementsByClassName("col-xs-12 col-md-3")(0).getElementsByTagName("b")(0)
sTD10 = ky.innerText